# Private class usage

Tags: java

I know that Java wouldn't allow us to define a top-level class as private, I saw answers in other questions claiming that it would be useless, but why useless? lets say I want a class which manages the employees' wage, and I don't want anyone to access this class and I don't need any other helper class, what is the problem defining it as private?

Comment: If nobody will access to that class, not even the JVM when executing the `public static void main(String[] args)` method, how would you use it?

Comment: **lets say I want a class which manages the employees' wage, and I don't want anyone to access this class and I don't need any other helper class, what is the problem defining it as private?** - The problem, well even you will not be able to access the class.

Comment: why? the main is a method in that class, and i'm running this class! I mean i'm in that class and just has to press play, why I can't access it?!?!

Comment: @OgeeGee: no, you won't be able to run it if it's private. the JVM will still need to be able to reach it.

Comment: But **nobody**, not even the JVM will be able **to access and use it**. If the JVM cannot access to this class, how it will invoke the entry point?

Comment: Got it, Thanks :), I just missed the first comment (JVM)!

Comment: If the intent is to have a class to which no other code in the JVM can ever have access, Java and the JVM just do not make that feasible.  Java agents can see all classes as they are loaded (except the core ones used to bootstrap the JVM and agent loading).  And, of course, even a protected class can be accessed by others.

Comment: Perhaps with a little more clarification of just what is being protected, we can help more.

Comment: How about putting a private inner class inside another one and only have the absolute bare-minimum exposed by the outer class (such as a `public static void main(String[] args)` if this is a command-line program.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Is it really the case that JVM will not be able to access and use `main()` methods in private top-level classes (if there were such things)? Insofar as I can tell, a lot of reflection magic happens before JVM invokes `main()`, which is why it is able to invoke `main()` methods in package-private classes. I get the impression that forbidding top-level classes is more of a decision than a necessity.

Comment: @JaeHeonLee from [JVM Specification. 5.2. Java Virtual Machine Startup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.2): *The Java Virtual Machine then links the initial class, initializes it, and invokes the `public` class method `void main(String[])`. The invocation of this method drives all further execution.* It doesn't say if it does it through reflection or by simple invocation of the method as is.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ...which would mean that it is not the case that "nobody, not even the JVM will be able to access and use it." No?

Comment: @JaeHeonLee it's not stated anywhere that the JVM could or couldn't access to this. We only have this part of the [JSL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6): ***It is a compile-time error if a top level type declaration contains any one of the following access modifiers: `protected`, `private`, or `static`.***

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm sorry -- I was quoting your comment above.

Answer (score 4):

A top level class defined as `private` would not be *accessible* to any class any where. You can have a top level class with `public`, `protected` or `package (default)` access. You can have `private` (or all other access levels) inner and static classes and `enum`s because the containing class (and to your point *only the containing class*) can see them.

Answer (score 2):

I think you confuse `class` and `class instance` in your question.

`Class` is like a blueprint, `Class instance` - is the object, built using this blueprint.

Assume you have defined this class as private at the top level, in this case no-one can build an object using this class. Your blueprint is closed in the box and no-one has access to this blueprint to build  an object.